# IE compatibility view or not?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

I have a web application designed to work well in < IE9 versions. With upgrades across the company to newer IE versions the application works well only if I turn on 'compatibility view'.

- Is it really a good thing? I mean, is it really the long term solution? Or should I start redesigning my application to support newer IE versions - even though I do not foresee to use any new features of HTML5?
- How long will MS be supporting 'compatibility view' switch? What in IE 12+ if there is no option like this?
- Is there any document gives the list of elements I should be looking to fix to    make my app compatible in old and newer IEs?

Comment: There are some sources for element compatibility across browsers and different versions of browsers, of which my favorite is [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it really a good thing? I mean, is it really the long term solution? Or should I start redesigning my application to support newer IE versions - even though I do not foresee to use any new features of HTML5?

No, it was never meant to be a long-term solution. You should definitely start redesigning your application if you can. You don't have to use any new HTML5 features in order to comply with Web standards — those are two different things entirely.

If your application does not work well in recent versions of IE, it's not because you're not using HTML5. It's more likely because it was designed in a way that relied on problems with older versions that caused them to behave in a non-standard manner. For example it may be relying on issues with how IE6 or IE7 handled certain HTML elements or CSS styles.

> How long will MS be supporting 'compatibility view' switch? What in IE 12+ if there is no option like this?

The Compatibility View button is already gone in IE11; the only way to force a site to use it is to add it to a list in Compatibility View settings as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321449.aspx). You can see that Microsoft is already taking measures to phase out this feature, albeit gradually.

You can also use the `X-UA-Compatible` header that was introduced in IE8 to [emulate IE7 document mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915.aspx):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

But even that has also been deprecated in IE11, so again if you do use it, know that it's no longer viable in the long run.

> Is there any document gives the list of elements I should be looking to fix to make my app compatible in old and newer IEs?

There isn't any single document that will help you with this because it's not just a matter of "fixing elements", it's a matter of developing with standards compliance in mind, which is a huge topic in itself.

Fortunately, there are many good resources out there today for helping you develop with the latest standards. In particular, when it comes to working with IE, a good starting resource is [modern.IE](http://modern.ie).

Comment: I have IE 11 and I was able to turn on Compatibility view. It's under Tools>Compatibility View Settings then add your domain to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to be adding a lot of features you don't really need to update it. You can force compatibility using headers within your page.

It's mostly js that breaks, though sometimes css/html a bit too.
Biggest issue: you probably need to upgrade your js libraries if you want to stay current, otherwise all that cross browser normalization of functions they do (unifying multiple browser implementations into 1 function) will be missing coverage for browser versions released after the release date of the js library.

In conclusion, I think it's safe to use the compatibility view and will save time/effort, but you should see if Microsoft provides a deprecation schedule. And if it's an application that will be around for a long time, you may want to get current just because theoretically it should be easier to upgrade with every cycle since it will force you to refactor into a more browser-agnostic codebase.

Also, check with your company -- for internal apps they usually control these things & will advise their employees not to upgrade until instructed to.